# Comparing Axiom of Specification vs Axiom of Universal Specification for cause of Russell's Paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Terence Tao's Analysis I 4th edition has a chapter on simple set theory, and introduces the Russel paradox as being caused by the Axiom of Universal Specification - but not caused by the more constrained Axion of Specification.

**Question** - what is the difference between the two, very similar, axioms that leads to the paradox?

---

For reference, here are the two axioms, slightly paraphrased:

**Axiom 3.6 (Axiom of specification, or axiom of separation)**. Let $A$ be a set, and for each $x \in A$, let $P(x)$ be a property pertaining to $x$. Then there exists a set, called $\{x \in A : P(x)\}$, whose elements are precisely the elements $x$ in $A$ for which $P(x)$ is true. In other words, for any object $y$,

$$y \in \{x \in A:P(x)\} \iff (y \in A \land P(y))$$

**Axiom 3.9 (Universal specification, or axiom of comprehension)**. Suppose for every object $x$ we have a property $P(x)$ pertaining to $x$. Then there exists a set $\{x : P(x)\}$ such that for every object $y$,

$$y \in \{x : P(x)\} \iff P(y)$$

---

**My Thoughts**

My thoughts are that Axiom 3.6 constructs a set from objects that belong to an existing set $A$. Axiom 3.9 constructs a set from objects which don't have to be from an existing set.

Therefore the set constructed by Axiom 3.6 is a subset.

However I can't continue this line of argument to say that a subset of an existing set can't lead to Russell's paradox?

Is it because the known set $A$ doesn't suffer the contradiction, and therefore neither can any subset?

Comment: Your first thought about the key difference between the two is correct.

Comment: And see [Axiom of Separation & Russell's Paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446378/axiom-of-separation-russells-paradox).

Comment: The "construction" of R's Paradox applied to Specification allows us to "curve out" **form an already existent set** $A$ the subset of all and only those elements that do not belong to themselves, and this is not an issue, because there is no reason to assume that $A$ belongs to itself.